# Recursion in Js

Tags: javascript, recursion

Can someone please explain to me why we need `(n-1)` in the following code.

```
  function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {    
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

I understand that we have a base case of `if (n <= 0){return 1}` inorder for the code to not loop for ever but I dont understand the `(n-1)` and `[n-1]` in the recursive case of  `return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];` .

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What else would you write there? Are you suggesting that passing `n` instead of `n-1` would also work?

Comment: "*I understand that we have a base case inorder for the code to not loop for ever*" - well, could explain in your own words how this "looping" works, how you would **reach** that base case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this function is meant to start with the last element of the array and recursively operate on each earlier element. This is why when calling the function recursively, you must pass in the next earlier element, i.e. `n-1`. This moves the function closer to the base case with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i understand it now

Comment: This can be much easier written with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

This function just multiplies all elements of the given array.
Initially you must pass the array and it's length as `n`.

The last element for any array is `n-1`. Thus on the 1st iteration it will take the last element and multiply further until it reaches 0. Then it will stop.

Just try to run this function mentally in your head on some simple examples and you'll get it.

Comment: Thanks for you help and advice i will do as you said

Answer (score 0):

The function could be improved, but you can understand it as-is by adding some debug logging...

```js
function multiply(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    console.log(`recurse to multiply ${arr[n-1]} by elements in [${arr.slice(0,n-1)}]`);
    return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
  }
}

multiply([1, 2, 3], 3);
```

A clearer implementation wouldn't require the length param, and be clearer about decomposition...

```js
// if the array has a first element, multiply it by the remainder of the array
function multiply(arr) {
  return arr.length ? arr[0] * multiply(arr.slice(1)) : 1;
}

console.log(multiply([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Your "better implementation" has a time complexity of `O(n²)` however, in contrast to the linear complexity of the original function.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. I considered that but figured it was more valuable for explaining recursion with the general form: "handle the first and recurse with the rest".  Edited to say what I meant by "better".